# Java Export - Text Files

Tags: java, text, file, export

I tried to export a Java program from Eclipse to a .jar file, but I came across a problem. It ran fine, but for some reason it didn't find the text files it was supposed to get data from. If anyone could help with this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I take it these text files are supposed to be packaged into the jar. Have you verified whether they are?

Answer (score 3):

Where are these text files ? If they're packaged within your .jar file, I would expect to be able to find them within the class hierarchy using [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), specifying the complete path relative to the classloader base.

Answer (score 0):

If your program depends on internal text files, put them in classpath and package them in the jar. Find them with the Class.getResourceAsStream.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we need some more information to help you solve this problem. Where are your text files located while debugging and developing your code? Make sure that they are accessible from the path you are running the jar in.

Comment: all of the files, text and source alike, are in the same package.